# D7+ i18n: What is the normal way: a single node with 2 translations or a different node for each translation

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am having a difficult to understand this issue:

My D7 + Internationalization create a different node for each translation. Is this the normal way? Than how does Drupal know they belong to a same article.
I remember in D6 was one node and one editing page for all the translations of the articles.

I think the normal way is to keep a single node and different paths with different prefix: /fi or /en.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the normal way. In /admin/content it lists the content and you can sort by language.

It knows which belong to which because it writes that info into the node table in the database by defining the 'tnid': The translation set id for this node, which equals the node id of the source post in each set.

Comment: So what you're saying it keeps different nodes for each translation for same content connected by tid?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. But by tnid (translation node id) not to be confused with tid (taxonomy term id).